# Increase the Logo size and navbar size in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can not find a genuine solution to my problem on the web.
I am a student and I am trying to create a sophisticated blog about the world.
I would like to have a bigger logo in my nav-bar, which works on multiple devices.
The standard bootstrap navbar is just to small.
[They have a good logo and navbar height](http://www.economist.com)

HTML SOURCE:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="7PAGES"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hover_wirtschaft">
                        <a href="#">Wirtschaft</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hover_technik">
                        <a href="#">Technik</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hover_fitness">
                        <a href="#">Fitness</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hover_wissenschaft">
                        <a href="#">Wissenschaft</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hover_entertainment">
                        <a href="#">Entertainment</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hover_reisen">
                        <a href="#">Reisen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hover_wohnen">
                        <a href="#">Wohnen</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
```

CSS code:

```
#logo {
max-width: 100px;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

I would appreciate any help, since I am stuck on this one.
Thanks in advance I know you guys at StackOverflow do a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a taller nav bar, just add this CSS:

```
.navbar {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

I picked `padding-top` to make the text links stay to the bottom of the nav.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the height of the **navbar**, you could do:

```
.navbar {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Have a look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8d7BY/).

Answer (score 0):

I have done this two-fold. First, my nav is set up like this (a little different because I have the image take up even more space in mobile and I am using Roots for WP):

```
    <header class="banner navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="banner">
    <div class="col-xs-4 margin-top-20 margin-bottom-20 visible-xs">
      <a href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>    
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="index.php"><img src="logo.png" style="width:auto;height:40px;"></a>
    </div>

    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="menu-about"><a href="about-us/">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-products"><a href="products/">Products</a></li>
        <li class="menu-equipment"><a href="equipment/">Equipment</a></li>
        <li class="menu-events"><a href="events/">Events</a></li>
        <li class="menu-resources"><a href="resources/">Resources</a></li>
        <li class="menu-contact"><a href="contact/">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="menu-order-online"><a href="order/">Order Online</a></li>
     </ul>    
   </nav> 
  </div>
</header>
```

Then I have overrides for Bootstrap:

`@navbar-padding-horizontal: floor((@grid-gutter-width / .2));
@navbar-height: 70px;`

When people suggest changing padding/height, you can easily do it using LESS. As an override it will carry through in updated Bootstrap versions better than CSS overrides (interdependencies).

Simply put, using LESS actually makes everything else calculate to the @navbar-height setting and then your navigation will appear vertically centered.

Adjust the navbar-height as needed to support your image.